# LinkedList findElement

Tags: java, linked-list

I try to use below code to find the last k-th element in the `LinkedList`.
Why does it always return `null`?

```
public Node findElem(Node head, int k){
    if(k < 1|| k > this.length()){
        System.out.println("error");
    }
    Node p1=head;
    Node p2 = head;
    for(int i=0;i<k-1;i++) {
        p1 = p1.next;
    }
    while(p1 != null){
            p1= p1.next;
            p2 = p2.next;
    }
    return p2;
}
```

Comment: Where did you get this code? It simply is not correct for multiple reasons. What you're doing right now is finding the `null` at the end of the linked list and returning it, not finding any particular element in any case.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to do with that code? I guess you're trying to find t Node in the LinkedList that is the k-th Node?
But in every way your code is completely useless.
It should be something like that:

```
public Node findElem(Node head, int k) {
    if(k < 1 || k > this.length()) {
        System.out.println("Error");
        return null;
    }
    Node position = head;
    while(k > 0) {
        position = position.next;
        k--;
    }
    return position;
}
```

Hope this is what you were looking for. If not feel free to ask me again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got it.

Comment: I believe this will find the K the node in the linked list not last k-th element in the LinkedList. For instance, if you have a linked list "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9" and you wanted to find out at position 9 it should give you 1 not 9.

Comment: Yeah, just change the k which is in while loop into (length - k). That will find the last k-th element.

Answer (score 0):

You only need one variable: reference to a k-th element on the list, which in your code is `p1`. Find that element as you do here:

```
for(int i=0; i<k-1;i++) {
    p1 = p1.next;
}
```

and then return it. Also, looking at your previous `if(k<1|| k>this.length())`, you except a non-zero number, so you should init `i` in the `for` loop to 1 because `head` would be the 1-st node in your linked list.